# Haskell Beam code only works in one module

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

I have `DatasourceId` defined in a `Schema` module like this

```
import qualified Database.Beam as B

data DatasourceT f = Datasource
  { _datasourceId :: B.C f Text 
  , _datasourceName :: B.C f Text 
  } deriving (Generic, B.Beamable)

instance B.Table DatasourceT where
  data PrimaryKey DatasourceT f = DatasourceId (B.C f Text) deriving (Generic, B.Beamable)
  primaryKey = DatasourceId . _datasourceId

type DatasourceId = B.PrimaryKey DatasourceT Identity
```

but I am not able to use it outside the `Schema` module as in

```
(B.val_ $ DatasourceId $ _datasourceId d)
```

because the compiler complains

```
>     • Data constructor not in scope:
>         DatasourceId :: t0 -> B.PrimaryKey DatasourceT Identity
>     • Perhaps you meant 'Datasource' (imported from Schema)
>     |
> 229 |  (B.val_ $ DatasourceId $ _datasourceId d)
```

even though I have

```
import Schema (ControlAccessDb(..), Datasource, DatasourceId, DatasourceT(..))
```

So is there any advice that can prevent the code from being doomed to be globbed into one module?  Is this perhaps a quirk of type families?
It seems that the problem lies in

```
instance B.Table DatasourceT where
  data PrimaryKey DatasourceT f = DatasourceId (B.C f Text) deriving (Generic, B.Beamable)
  primaryKey = DatasourceId . _datasourceId
```

where the instanciation innards are only made known to the defining module.

Note that the Beam doc itself has such usage (code embedded in the doc). See https://tathougies.github.io/beam/user-guide/manipulation/insert/ where `CustomerId` is defined at https://github.com/tathougies/beam/blob/d87120b58373df53f075d92ce12037a98ca709ab/beam-sqlite/examples/Chinook/Schema.hs#L119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat unintuitive situation that occurs anywhere attached types are used, not specific to Beam.

Because `DatasouceId` is a constructor of the attached type `PrimaryKey`, you need to export and import that type, just like you would with a normal, non-attached type. This is somewhat unintuitive, because `PrimaryKey` is not originally defined in your module. But in a sense, it is: you're defining an instance of that type, so you get to export it too. I guess that must be the arguable logic behind this.

Export from your `Schema` module like this:

```
module Schema( ..., B.PrimaryKey(..), ... ) where
```

Import wherever you need it like this:

```
import Schema(PrimaryKey(..))
```

Comment: The export should be qualified, so I think you mean
```module Schema( ..., B.PrimaryKey(..), ... ) where```

Comment: Yes, you're right: in your case, since `Database.Beam.Schema` is imported as qualified, you should refer to `PrimaryKey` with a qualification as well. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Would your approach still work if I have several type synonyms such as 
`type D2Id = B.PrimaryKey D2T Identity` ?

Comment: "Work" in what way?

Comment: Regarding `Database.Beam.Schema` -- that does not exist. `Schema` is my own module.

Comment: It's imported from `Database.Beam` in your code, but the class `Table` really comes from `Database.Beam.Schema`, it's just reexported from `Database.Beam`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `Table` is a class, whereas `PrimaryKey` is an attached type. This means, roughly, that "every instance of `Table` must have some definition of `PrimaryKey` attached to it". You are defining both. You are defining an instance of `PrimaryKey` as a `data` type with one constructor named `DatasourceId`.